# Construct a tree from a list of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, hierarchical-clustering

Suppose I have a list of numbers like below,

```
a = [1,23,5,72,3,5,15,7,78,1,5,77,23]
```

Now I need to build a tree from these data.

> 1. Divide the dataset into two parts according to the self-defined function `par`. Let's call these two parts a0, a1.
> 2. Apply the function `par` on a0, a1 respectively, and get a00, a01, a11, a12.
> 3. Repeat the process until there is only one number left at the end node.
> 4. For each end node, we have a "binary code" like "0010100", where 0 represents left, and 1 represents right at each specific step.

I was trying to use the tree class like below, but I was stuck at the first place.

```
class Node(input):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = '*'
        self.right = '*'
```

Comment: You're focusing on how to store it. Think about how to do the partitioning instead.

Comment: what will be the root of this tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear which values the *internal* nodes would have. It is maybe not important, but you could assign always the *first* value in the data array that belongs to that particular subtree.

The "binary code" is like a navigation path from the root to the node. So for the data you presented, we would expect something like this tree:

```
value:                                   1
path:                       ____________ "" ________ 
                           /                        \
value:                    1                         15
path:                  __ 0 __                 _____ 1 _______
                      /       \               /               \
value:              1         72             15                1
path:               00        01             10             __ 11 __
                   /  \      /  \           /  \           /        \
value:            1   23    72   3         15   7         1          77
path:            000  001   010  011      100  101       110         111
                     /  \       /  \          /  \       /  \       /   \
value:              23   5     3    5        7    78    1    5     77   23
path:              0010 0011  0110 0111    1010  1011  1100 1101  1110 1111
```

You can use a simple `Node` class, which can store both a value and a path:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, path, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.path = path
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

The `par` function would do something like this:

```
def par(data):
    i = len(data) // 2
    return (data[:i], data[i:]) if i else ()
```

The `if..else` operator is used to return an empty list when there is only one data element. This will be useful in the main function:

```
def maketree(data, path=""):
    return Node(data[0], path, *(
        maketree(part, path + str(i)) for i, part in enumerate(par(data))
    ))
```

This enumerates the parts that are returned by `par` and passes those parts to the recursive call (if any parts are returned). At the same time that recursive call gets a path string that is extended with a 0 or 1 (i.e. the index of the enumeration).

Example call:

```
a = [1,23,5,72,3,5,15,7,78,1,5,77,23]
root = maketree(a)

# Output the properties of one particular node:
node = root.left.left.right.left
print("value: {}, path: {}".format(node.value, node.path))
# Outputs: "value: 23, path: 0010"
```

Comment: very helpful solution. By the way, do I need to make a memorization wrapper for the recursive function? @trincot

Comment: Memoization is not useful here: that would only serve a purpose if there was a probability that a node was visited a second time, and the same information would need to be calculated for it. But that is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Node(input):
    def __init__(self, data, path='0'):
        self.path = path # 0 means left, 1 means right
        if len(data) = 1:
            self.value = data[0] # this assumes the leaf is a list with single data, rather than the data itself
        else:
            left, right = par(data)
            left = Node(left, side+'0')
            right = Node(right, side+'1')
```

Node.path gives you the binary code.